# When (and why) is {} undefined in a JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, console

In the console of both FF and Chrome, {} is considered undefined until explicitly evaluated:

```
{};     // undefined
({});   // ▶ Object
```

Actually, it's a bit less defined than undefined -- it's apparently bad syntax:

```
{} === undefined;  // SyntaxError: Unexpected token ===
{}.constructor;    // SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

But not if it's on the other side, in which case it's fine:

```
"[object Object]" == {}.toString(); // true
```

Or if it's not the first expression:

```
undefined + undefined; // NaN
{} + undefined;        // NaN
undefined + {};        // "undefined[object Object]"
```

What gives?

Comment: ...What the f{UNDEFINED}? isn't really that appropriate. Can you rephrase?

Comment: The consoles does not necessarily map explicitly to normal JS. I know for instance that (I don't remember if this was the chrome or the FF console) that if you type `$(id)` you it would evaluate to `document.getElementById(id)` (which would break with jQuery for instance).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, here is my answer. There is nothing new here. I am just linking to (a pretty copy of) the ECMAScript specification for the grammar and showing a few productions to show "why" it parses the way it does. In any case, the behavior is well-defined according to the JavaScript/ECMAScript grammar rules: `{}` is parsed differently depending upon the "context" it is in.

---

The JavaScript [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop)s ("consoles") start to parse the code in the [`Statement`](http://es5.github.com/#A.4) grammar production or "statement context". (This is actually a lie, it starts at the `Program` or `SourceElements` production, but that adds additional constructs to dig through.) Here is a rough grammar breakdown with simplifications and omissions; see the link above for more:

```
Statement
    Block
    ...
    ExpressionStatement

Block
    # This is actually { StatementList[optional] }, but this is what
    # it amounts to: * means "0 or more".
    { Statement* }

ExpressionStatement
    # An ExpressionStatement can't start with "{" or "function" as
    # "{" starts a Block and "function" starts a FunctionStatement.
    [lookahead ∉ {{, function}]Expression ;

Expression
    # This is really PrimaryExpression; I skipped a few steps.
    ...
    ( Expression )
```

Thus (when in "statement context"):

```
   {}
-> Block  # with no StatementList (or "0 statements")
-> Statement
```

And:

```
   ({})
-> (Expression)
-> Expression
-> ExpressionStatement  # omitted in productions below
-> Statement
```

This also explains why `undefined === {}` parses as `EXPR === EXPR -> EXPR -> STMT` and results in false when evaluated. The `{}` in this case is in an "expression context".

In the case of `{} === undefined` it is parsed as `{}; === undefined`, or `BLOCK; BOGUS -> STMT; BOGUS`, which is a Syntax Error. However, with the addition of parenthesis this changes: `({} === undefined)` is parsed as `(EXPR === EXPR) -> (EXPR) -> EXPR -> STMT`.

In the case of `{} + "hi"` it is parsed as `{}; + "hi"`, or `BLOCK; + EXPR -> STMT; EXPR -> STMT; STMT`, which is valid syntax even though it is silly (`+` is unary in this case). Likewise, just as above, `"hi" + {}` puts the `{}` into an "expression context" and it is parsed as `EXPR + EXPR -> EXPR -> STMT`.

The JavaScript console is just showing the result of the last Statement, which is "undefined" (well, "nothing" really, but that doesn't exist) for an empty `{}` block. (This might vary between browsers/environments as to what is returned in this case, e.g. last ExpressionStatement only?)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 11):

If you use the curly brackets by themselves, it's not an object literal, it's a code block. As the code block doesn't contain any code, evaluating it results in `undefined`.

Comment: The same goes for the other forms that work: in those cases the `{}` appears as an *expression*.

Comment: This does not explain how "{}===undefined" is a syntax error, and "undefined==={}" is not.

Comment: @JS_Riddler Yes it does. `{} === undefined` is parsed as `{}; === undefined` as `{}` appears in a location where it is *not* read as an expression. `({} === undefined)` would work. This is because, in the latter case, the parser read the `{}` as an object literal ("as an expression").

Comment: @JS_Riddler Because in the latter case, the right-hand expression is strictly treated as an object literal. In the former case, there's ambiguity, but the parser seems to favor the block interpretation.

Comment: I see.  So:  if "{}" is the first expression, it is treated as a block.

Answer (score 2):

If you just type `{}` as input in any console, there is no context to interpret what you want the curly braces to mean, other than it's position. given the fact each input to the console is interpreted as fresh line of code, the opening curly brace is seen as the start of a new block. The closing `}` is syntactically correct, since an empty block is often used in situations like these:

```
try
{
    //something
}
catch(e)
{}//suppress error
```

Hence `{}` will always be undefined when it is on the left hand side, and never spit errors as an empty block is valid code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like both consoles treat it as an ambiguous condition when the expression starts with `{`. Maybe it is treated as a dummy block.

Try this:

```
{} // undefined
undefined === {} // false
```

Using `{}` as a right-hand-expression removes the ambiguity.

Also you can see from:

```
{a:42} // 42
{{a:42}} // 42
{{{a:42}}} // 42
```

That the outer braces are really treated as a dummy block.

And this doesn't seem to be a console feature. Even `eval` treats them like that, hinting to the fact that the stuff you type in the console actually get evaluated the same way they would when passed to `eval`:

```
eval("{}") // undefined
eval("{alert(42)}") // alerts 42
```

Comment: {} === undefined is a SyntaxError, why?

Comment: @JS_Riddler, for the same reason this is: `{alert("hi")} === undefined`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to have `{}` on its own. Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in some cases, javascript sees { and } as opening and closing a /block/. While in other cases, {} is an object. The cases really depend on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Doug Crockford complains about this. That WTF you're getting there is due to the + operator itself. It's used to both to arithmetic and concatenate. In your last line there, you're seeing the + operator convert undefined and the empty object to strings, and concatenating them.

Comment: This is not the issue in this case. Try: `{} + "fails because {} is a block and not an expression"` and `"okay because {} is now an expression" + {}`.

Comment: No, those both concatenate... The first will evaluate to "[object Object]fails because {} is a block and not an expression" and the second "okay because {} is now an expression[object Object]"

Comment: @pst: it's not a syntax error. the first on is actually: `{}; + "somestring"..`. which tries to convert the string to number and you get `NaN`

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte The fact that it is on the *right* side of a `=` puts it in an "expression context". Try running the code the poster posted, as the poster posted it :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript separates the concept of statements and expressions (languages like C++ or Java do the same).

For example `if ...` is a statement, and `x?y:z` is an expression.

Expressions have a value, statements do not.

One problem with Javascript syntax is that `{}` can be either an expression (and in this case it means an empty object constructor) or a statement (and in this case it means an empty code block... basically a NOP) so how it's interpreted depends on the context.